# Find index of given element or NA if given element does not appear

Tags: r, function

I've been stuck for hours on a problem. If any of you have an idea how to solve it, thanks a lot.

So I am trying to learn how to write a function f that takes an input (numeric) vector 'vec' and an integer 'int'.

Basically, the function should return where does 'int' appear in 'vec', and if 'int' does not appear in 'vec' so the function should return 'NA'.

All this by using a loop 'for'.

Finally, the output of

````
sapply(1:4, function(x) print(f3(c(3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1), x))) is

#    ```
#    [1] 6
#    [1] 4 5
#    [1] 1 2 3
#    NULL
````

here's my code, but I'm stuck here and don't see the solution to my problem.

```
    f <- function(vec, int) {
  for (i in vec) 
    check <- vec[]== int 
  which(int == vec)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

```
f <- function(vec, int){
  if(all(vec != int)) return(NA)
  
  for(i in vec){
    if(i == int) return(which(vec == i))
  }
}
```

And then you can check that it works, for example, by:

```
vect <- sample(1:10, 1000, replace = T)
inte <- 10

f(vect, inte)
```

Comment: The code, as written, does not make sense: you’re looping over `vec` but you always return in the first iteration of the loop so the loop does nothing (except being skipped entirely when `vec` is empty.

Comment: nice, I really couldn't see the solution to my problem for hours. Thank u so much for your help (:

Comment: @Konrad was right about the code. I just corrected it.

Comment: The fix improves things but I still don’t think the code does anything meaningful. Doesn’t it just do the same as `which(vec == int)`, except returning `NA` instead of `integer(0` when there’s no hit? The `for` loop is simply redundant.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, yes, as you say the `for` loop doesn't make much sense. However, the original question requested it.

Answer (score 0):

What you’ve described is essentially what `which` does already anyway. The only difference is that `which` returns `integer(0)` (that is, an empty vector) in case of no hit instead of `NA`.

So all you need to do in your `f` is call `which` and “fix” the result:

```
f = function (vec, x) {
    result = which(vec, x)
    if (length(result) == 0L) NA_integer_ else result
}
```

The code `if (length(…) == 0L) ‹A› else ‹B›` is such a common pattern that people often define a specific operator for it:

```
`%||%` = function (a, b) {
    if (length(a) == 0L) b else a
}
```

With that function you can simplify `f` (and similar functions) considerably:

```
f = function (vec, x) {
    which(vec, x) %||% NA_integer_
}
```